# Sampling data techniques for Netezza/large databases

Tags: database, bigdata, data-warehouse, netezza, random

We are using IBM's Netezza. We have a table which gets nearly 10 billion records daily which we need to process. One of the fields of the table identifies a user through a 38 character numeric string, lets call it UserID. We have this table distributed on the UserID. I am looking for an optimum sampling technique. Currently, we sample using mod(UserID,SamplingRate) = 0 but since this table is distributed on the UserID, I think there must surely be a better way.

In Hive, we have the notion of buckets, where in we can divide our tables into some buckets and then fetch one of the bucket altogether which gives good performance.

**Update:**
By sampling data, I mean to get at random 500 million records with uniform distribution. The number of records that I want to get can be determined based on my sampling rate.
Datatype for UserID is numeric(38). (Java: BigDecimal)

Comment: What do you mean by sampling?  Do you just want a random subset of the 10 billion records?

Comment: Also what `datatype` is the `userID` field?

Comment: Updated the description with more information.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple random sample in where condition? thats resolved in planning so it should run smoothly, so far rand() has uniform distribution:

```
SELECT * FROM BIGTABLE WHERE RAND()< SAMPLE_SIZE/BIGTABLE_TOTAL;
```